# In which case does a java garbage collection of the young generation last long?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

yesterday we had the following GC output in our server log of one JBoss application server:

```
51628.286: [GC 51628.288: [ParNew: 1843200K->204800K(1843200K), 21.3196040 secs]
5177730K->3743415K(7987200K), 21.3217870 secs]
[Times: user=1.38 sys=0.33, real=21.32 secs]
```

I understand the output like this: the young generation is sized 1843200K. The size before generation was 1843200K, the size after 204800K. The collection lasted 21.3 seconds.

Normally our young generation collections last <1 sec. Under which circumstances do yg collections last so long?

Our JVM params:

```
-server 
-verbose:gc
-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps
-XX:+PrintGCDetails 
-XX:NewRatio=3
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC 
-XX:+UseParNewGC 
-XX:+UseCMSCompactAtFullCollection 
-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=60 
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m 
-Xss512k 
-Xms8000m 
-Xmx8000m
```

java version:

```
java version "1.6.0_29"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_29-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.4-b02, mixed mode)
```

Thanks,
Marcel

Answer (score 7):

We had a tomcat server which had garbage collections which lasted ~2 minutes. Eventually, we found the reason, we had allocated more memory to the JVM through -Xmx than we had physical memory on the system. This was causing paging during the garbage collection, which kills it.

Also, we had multiple VMs which were running on the same physical machine. Make sure that you have not allocated more memory to all of the VMs than you have physical memory on the server.

For further information, see [Tuning the Memory Management System, section Setting the Heap Size](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/geninfo/diagnos/memman.html) (my emphasis):

> Command line options: -Xms: -Xmx:
>
> The heap size has an impact on allocation speed, garbage collection
>   frequency and garbage collection times. A small heap will become full
>   quickly and must be garbage collected more often. It is also prone to
>   more fragmentation, making object allocation slower. A large heap
>   introduces a slight overhead in garbage collection times. **A heap that
>   is larger than the available physical memory in the system must be
>   paged out to disk, which leads to long access times or even
>   application freezes, especially during garbage collection**.

Comment: +1. Set up a disk activity monitor to see if disk is saturated during GC.

Comment: We are monitoring the available linux memory. It was never > 80%. So no swapping.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the concurrent garbage collector (`-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC` ), which runs in a separate thread. From the Times output you posted, it looks like the garbage collector itself did not run long. I would guess that your system did not have enough CPU time left for the GC to run, so it took 20 s for the GC to get the 1 s of CPU time it needed. When using the concurrent GC you should make sure that your application does not eat up all of the CPU time.

Otherwise another thing can happen: If the concurrent collector is not able to free enough memory and reaches a certain barrier it will do a Full GC which will block all other threads and consume a lot of time. This Full GC has a slightly different output though (says `Full GC` instead of `GC`), so I guess this is not your problem here.

Comment: The question was about a young generation collection. I don't think the fact the he used a concurrent collector for the tenured generation is relevant.

Comment: CPU consumption wasn't the problem

Answer (score 0):

I believe that's counting wall-clock time, so if other processes interrupt the GC and run for a while, then that will be misreported.

There shouldn't be anything in the young generation that causes the collection to take a long time -- the cost of the GC is proportional to the number of reachable items, and your numbers showed that only a fraction was still reachable.

Reference queue management and running finalizers can take up significant amounts of time but should not (??) count towards that number.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html has tips on GC tuning.

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled over an [article](https://blogs.oracle.com/jonthecollector/entry/did_you_know) saying that having huge methods can cause long GC pauses (It's the last section) Excerpt:

> When a method is compiled, the compilers generate and save information on where object references live **(This helps GC and is called oop map)** Methods larger than a certain size will not be JIT'ed in hotspot. ... If the method has not been JIT'ed, the GC has to generate the oop maps itself during the GC. ... Large methods mean large abstract interpretation times to generate the oop maps. .... By the way, the huge method was something like 2500 lines so it was what I would call huge.

(Text in bold was inserted)